# How to search items in AWS Amplify Datastore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

In my react native app with AWS amplify backend I want to search 'product' model.

At the moment I'm doing it like this first I query all the products like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    
 const getallProducts = async () => {
  
 await DataStore.query(Product).then(setAllProducts);
 
};
getallProducts();

}, []);
```

Then I filter these products to show the search results to the User.

But I want to implement this search function without querying all products to the device. How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried [Docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js/#querying-for-a-single-item) ?

Comment: @Kaneki21 Yes but I couldn't find anything related to this, but I will check again